# Error with find using BeautifulSoup doing webscrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find

I have the code below which is extracting information from coingecko doing webscrapping. Its been working for the past days but today got this issue.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[99], line 11
      9 htmlContent = r.content
     10 soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent,'html.parser')
---> 11 results = soup.find('div' , {'class': 'coingecko-table'}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
     12 print('Reading page' + str(i))
     13 for result in results:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

--
This is the code I am using:

```
names =[] 
prices =[] 
vol_24h = []
market_Cap = []

for i in range (1 ,2): 
    url = "https://www.coingecko.com/?page=" + str(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    htmlContent = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent,'html.parser')
    results = soup.find('div' , {'class': 'coingecko-table'}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    print('Reading page' + str(i))
    for result in results:
        try:
            names.append(result.find('td', {'class':'py-0 coin-name cg-sticky-col cg-sticky-third-col px-0'}).get_text().strip()) 
        except:
            names.append('n/a')
        try:
            prices.append(result.find('td', {'class':'td-price price text-right'}).get_text().strip())
        except:
            prices.append('n/a')
        try:
            vol_24h.append(result.find('td', {'class':'td-liquidity_score lit text-right col-market'}).get_text().strip())
        except:
            vol_24h.append('n/a')
        try:
            market_Cap.append(result.find('td', {'class':'td-market_cap cap col-market cap-price text-right'}).get_text().strip())
        except:
            market_Cap.append('n/a')
```

Would someone be able to help me? thanks!

Comment: That means that it didn't find the table, or the table doesn't contain `tbody`. You should check that each `find()` is successful before calling the next one, rather than chaining them.

Comment: Or put the code inside `try/except` so you can catch the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code and found the reason, the site has a simple anti-crawler policy that checks for 'User-Agent'. So you only need to add "User-Agent" in the request header when requesting, python has a package "fake-useragent" that can do this more conveniently. Change your request part to something like this. By the way, you may need to install it before using it: `pip install fake-useragent`

```py
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
...
ua = UserAgent()
r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": ua.random})
...
```